# How to sort json file into postgres table?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

i have a json file that i need to split on parts and sort every part to his column.

this is my table:

```
create table json_data(
row_id int,
id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
created_at timestamp ,
closed_at timestamp ,
open boolean,
num_changes int,
user_name varchar,
uid int,
min_lat real,
max_lat real,
min_lon real,
max_lon real,
created_by varchar,
imagery_used varchar,
version varchar,
comment varchar
);
```

and this is my Json file example:

```
{"id":"19739143","created_at":"2013-12-31T22:28:28Z","closed_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:11Z","open":"false","num_changes":"81","user":"47NOE","uid":"1811738","min_lat":"18.0813259","max_lat":"18.1163397","min_lon":"-63.0392394","max_lon":"-63.0205645","created_by":"Potlatch 2","build":"2.3-605-gbec0ea7","version":"2.3"}
{"id":"19739670","created_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:13Z","closed_at":"2013-12-31T23:59:15Z","open":"false","num_changes":"17","user":"mituc","uid":"1860759","min_lat":"37.0432953","max_lat":"37.0619236","min_lon":"-76.3896156","max_lon":"-76.3625439","created_by":"iD 1.3.4","imagery_used":"Bing"}
```

i have tried the following code, but if one of the pieces is missing (like "open:" for examlpe) then all data just slide left and shows wrong answer:

```
SELECT trim('{id:' from split_part(data, ',', 1)) AS id
      ,trim('created_at:' from split_part(data, ',', 2)) AS created_at
      ,trim('closed_at:' from split_part(data, ',', 3)) AS closed_at
      ,trim('open:' from split_part(data, ',', 4))AS open
      ,trim('num_changes:' from split_part(data, ',', 5)) AS num_changes
      ,trim('user:' from split_part(data, ',', 6)) AS user_name
      ,trim('uid:' from split_part(data, ',', 7)) AS uid
      ,trim('min_lat:' from split_part(data, ',', 8)) AS min_lat
      ,trim('max_lat:' from split_part(data, ',', 9)) AS max_lat
      ,trim('min_lon:' from split_part(data, ',', 10)) AS min_lon
      ,trim('max_lon:' from split_part(data, ',', 11)) AS max_lon
      ,trim('created_by:' from split_part(data, ',', 12)) AS col12 
      ,trim('build:' from split_part(data, ',', 13)) AS col13 
      ,trim('comment:' from split_part(data, ',', 13)) AS col13 
      ,trim('imagery_used:' from split_part(data, ',', 13)) AS col13
      ,trim('}' from trim('version:' from split_part(data, ',', 14))) AS col14   
FROM   json_data_raw;
```

or

```
SELECT trim('{id:' from split_part(data, ',', 1)) AS id
      ,trim('created_at:' from split_part(data, ',', 2)) AS created_at

,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 3) from 1 for 10) = 'closed_at:' 
then trim('closed_at:' from split_part(data, ',', 3))
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 4) from 1 for 10) = 'closed_at:' 
then trim('closed_at:' from split_part(data, ',', 3))
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 5) from 1 for 10) = 'closed_at:' 
then trim('closed_at:' from split_part(data, ',', 3))
else null
end
AS closed_at
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 4) from 1 for 5) = 'open:' 
then trim('open:' from split_part(data, ',', 4)) 
else null
end
AS open
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 5) from 1 for 12) = 'num_changes:' 
then trim('num_changes:' from split_part(data, ',', 5)) 
else null
end
AS num_changes
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 6) from 1 for 4) = 'user:' 
then trim('user:' from split_part(data, ',', 6))  
else null
end
AS user
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 7) from 1 for 4) = 'uid:' 
then trim('uid:' from split_part(data, ',', 7))  
else null
end
AS uid
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 8) from 1 for 8) = 'min_lat:' 
then trim('min_lat:' from split_part(data, ',', 8))  
else null
end
AS min_lat
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 9) from 1 for 8) = 'max_lat:' 
then trim('max_lat:' from split_part(data, ',', 9))  
else null
end
AS max_lat
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 10) from 1 for 8) = 'min_lon:' 
then trim('min_lon:' from split_part(data, ',', 10))  
else null
end
AS min_lon
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 11) from 1 for 8) = 'max_lon:' 
then trim('min_lon:' from split_part(data, ',', 11))  
else null
end
AS max_lon
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 12) from 1 for 11) = 'created_by:' 
then trim('created_by:' from split_part(data, ',', 12))  
else null
end
AS created_by
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 13) from 1 for 6) = 'build:' 
then trim('build:' from split_part(data, ',', 13))  
else null
end
AS build 
,case
when substring(split_part(data, ',', 14) from 1 for 8) = 'version:' 
then trim('version:' from split_part(data, ',', 14))   
else null
end
AS version_n
FROM   json_data_raw;
```

how can i sort it so that each piece will be sort to the correct column.

Comment: Does the JSON file have to go directly into PostgreSQL?  Personally I would use a script to convert it to a bunch of SQL inserts that could be imported into the database, or directly connects to the db and loads them in for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're parsing JSON using string manipulation functions like `split_part`.  But Postgres has [native JSON support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).  You can convert a string to JSON with `::json`.  You can query a JSON object like `->>'id'`.  For example:

```
select  data::json->>'id' as id
,       data::json->>'created_at' as created_at
from    json_data_raw
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4838b/2/0)

Comment: Hallo Andomar, i used                                                                              " create table json_data_raw(row_id serial primary key,  data text); "     to create table and then                                                                           " copy json_data_raw (data) from '/home/ramnikov/Downloads/osm-meta-util-master/examples/output.json' delimiters '#' csv;  "          to import json file into table json_data_raw. how would you import json file in this case?

Comment: My json file has more than 22000 lines so i can't do it like this:insert into json_data_raw values ('{"id":"19739143","created_at":"2013-12-31T22:28:28Z"}');

Comment: if i do it your way i get this error: ********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Token "id" is invalid.
Context: JSON data, line 1: {id...

Comment: i have solved  it. first i need to create table withe type json( create table tab( data json); ) and then import json file into it: copy json_data_raw (data) from '/path_to_file/output.json' csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02';